# How to manage multiple errors during a script process

Tags: php, database, error-handling, filesystems, structure

I have a php class that allow me to create, update & delete profile.

The delete method do basically the following:

- Get information about the profile from the db;
- Delete the profile from the db;
- Remove any profile relation from the db;
- Delete profile assets on the server (ie. photo, uploads, etc...);
- and so on...

My question is, how can I implement an error system for the whole process.

For example, what if, for example, the script blocked at "Remove any profile relation from the db" because of an unexpected error?

Is there any validation that can be done before processing to make sure that deletion won't stop at the middle of the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for database [transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php). You could start a transaction, then put all you database calls after it, commit the transaction. If any thing goes wrong-- you can rollback to the original state.

Your code might follow the pattern below:

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
   //Your delete proceedure
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

This will only work for the database piece.

Comment: Thanks... exactly what I was looking for :)